# Spatie/Laravel-Permission mapping permissions with controller methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authorization

does anyone know a way of mapping the controller methods with permissions authorisation?

Let's say that I have 20 controllers, with `index`,`store`,`show` and `delete` methods and I don't wanna put in each method of this controller the correspondent permission, just for the sake of ... DRY.

What I wanna do instead is trying to map the permissions with controller actions.

An example would be:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#writing-gates

> Gate::resource('posts', 'PostPolicy');
>
> This is identical to manually defining the following Gate definitions:
>
> Gate::define('posts.view', 'PostPolicy@view');
>
> Gate::define('posts.create', 'PostPolicy@create');
>
> Gate::define('posts.update', 'PostPolicy@update');
>
> Gate::define('posts.delete', 'PostPolicy@delete');

for me something like this would fit:

```
Permission::map('route', 'permission');
Permission::map('users.store', 'create-user');
```

or even better

```
Permission::mapResource('users', '????');
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Trait for that, if you have a better suggestion please.

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Pluralizer;
use Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\UnauthorizedException;

trait Authorisation
{
    private $permissions = [
        'index'   => 'view',
        'store'   => 'create',
        'show'    => 'view',
        'update'  => 'edit',
        'destroy' => 'delete'
    ];

    private $action;

    public function callAction($method, $parameters)
    {

        $permission = $this->getPermission($method);

        if(($permission && Auth::user()->can($permission)) || !$permission)
            return parent::callAction($method, $parameters);

        if(Request::ajax()) {
            return response()->json([
                'response' => str_slug($permission.'_not_allowed', '_')
            ], 403);
        }

        throw UnauthorizedException::forPermissions([$permission]);
    }

    public function getPermission($method)
    {
        if(!$this->action = array_get($this->getPermissions(), $method)) return null;

        return  $this->routeName() ?  $this->actionRoute() : $this->action;
    }

    public function registerActionPermission($action, $permission) {
        $this->permissions[$action] = $permission;
    }

    private function actionRoute() {
        return Pluralizer::singular($this->action . '-' . $this->routeName());
    }

    private function routeName() {
        return explode('.', Request::route()->getName())[0];
    }

    private function getPermissions()
    {
        return $this->permissions;
    }
}
```

And use it in controller like:

```
use Authorisation;
```

and if a want a custom permission for an action which does not exist in the `$permissions`:

```
$this->registerActionPermission('action_name', 'action-permission');
```